# ValidationFor do the validation before I write at the field

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following code in my Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The filed is required.")]
[Display(Name = "Number: ")]
public string NUM { get; set; }
```

View:

```
 <div class="col-lg-4">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.NUM) %>
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NUM, new {  @class = " form-control"}) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NUM,null , new { @class="text-danger"}) %>
        </div>
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Create(SINCO model)
    {
        Combo();

        PopulateItemChoices(model);
        return View(model);
    }
```

When I enter the page, before I write any data at the fields, this message (The field is required) already appears.

There are another pages in this site that this don't happen (it does the validation only when I write at the filed), so I can't understand what is wrong...

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I realized that  this happens in pages that I'm using the following jquery event, but I still dont know why is causing this error:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
           $('#IDMUN').change(function () {
               $.ajax({
                   url: 'MyFunction',
                   type: 'POST',
                   data: { Id: $(this).val() },
                   datatype: 'json',
                   success: function (data) {
                       var options = '';
                       for(var i in data){
                           options += '<option value="' + data[i].idLo + '">' + data[i].NameLo + '</option>';
                       }
                       $('#IDLO').prop('disabled', false).html(options);
                   }
               });
           });
       });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi in my opinion you're calling:

public ActionResult Create(SINCO model)

This invoke model binding, try this:
public ActionResult Create()
O
Just for detect if it works like attend.
How do you call create method?